# Instantiating custom C# classes from IronPython

Tags: c#, class, ironpython, embedding

Is there any way to make a class available to IronPython scripts so that I can create objects inside the code?

For example, if I have a class that I want to be able to instantiate from the script called MyClass defined in the C# code like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    string text;

    public MyClass(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

How can I do this in the Python script?

```
obj = MyClass("Hello, World!")
obj.Write()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming MyClass is in MyAssembly.dll:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('MyAssembly.dll')
import MyClass
obj = MyClass("Hello, World!")
obj.Write()
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to do some magic to make it work but it will :)

Comment: For me works as `clr.AddReference('MyAssembly')` - without `.dll`

Comment: AddReference didn't work for me but AddReferenceToFileAndPath did (I used absolute paths).
If have an **exe** then check our this page **how to build a dll**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio