# How steamkit work?

Tags: python, c#-4.0, steam, steam-web-api, steambot

Currently, i want to implement a trading system for steam games (with python).

So, i searched github, but sadly, there are only

## https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot

## https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamKit2

Yeah, they works good. But they are C# -- don't tell me python can't do this :).

So, i want to start with the steamkit part. I thought it's not difficult(maybe just some web-apis), but when i kinda review the code of SteamKit2, i find it seems use TcpConnection to Steam Network, don't know how they get the protocol.

Does anyone has any idea about this, i think about use python load steamkit2.dll, but im really noob with C#

Comment: I'm a total troglodyte when it comes to C#, but I think IronPython can use C# classes and libraries; like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870943/instantiating-custom-c-sharp-classes-from-ironpython

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to use the SteamKit2 port on that repository. It is a branch (and an out dated one at that) of the official [SteamKit2](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit) repository. It also looks like they are attempting to get rid of the branch based on this [issue](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/issues/234) discussion.

To answer your question, there is a [port](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/wiki/Ports) of SteamKit to Python. It is called [PySteamKit](https://bitbucket.org/AzuiSleet/pysteamkit) and is written by one of the contributors to SteamKit2.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much documentation in the Wiki of either the official SteamKit or the Python port on how to use the package. You may have to look at the Samples provided by SteamKit which are in C#.